# Async upload to Azure isn't blocking even though calling Task.WaitAll(task)

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, blob, task

I am uploading a file to Azure. The code uploads the file fine, but my page refreshes before it's finalized and shows the old image. I can refresh the page manually and it shows the new image. Why isn't my method waiting for the task to finish?

```
    public static bool Upload(Stream image, String id)
    {
        try {
            var key = String.Format("{0}.png", id);

            image.Position = 0;

            var container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Host, Container)), Credentials);

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(key);

            blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

            Task task = Task.Run(() => { blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image); });

            Task.WaitAll(task);
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**ANSWER:** So thanks to aleksey.berezan. The answer turned out to be not even using the task.

So this:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => { blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image); });

Task.WaitAll(task);
```

Became this:

```
Task.WaitAll(blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image));
```

And everything worked perfectly!

Comment: offtop: `catch { return false; }` - do try this at home, but not on the job

Comment: How do you call the `Upload` method? could you please post code of your page?

Comment: Yea, the catch thing was shorthand. I hadn't fully implemented the error handling yet. And the call is just a basic static call. DataStorageUtility.Upload(data.Image.InputStream, id);

Comment: does it work if instead of `Task` you call it directly `blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image);`?

Comment: Thanks aleksey.berezan! That worked perfect. Write this as an answer and I'll mark it answered for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This guy:

```
blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image);
```

starts new task.
Hence this guy:

```
Task.Run(() => { blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image); });
```

just starts task which starts task. So that this code:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => { blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image); });

Task.WaitAll(task);
```

will just wait until upload-task gets fired(which happens kinda immediately) but not for the completion of upload-task.

To fix the situation you'll have to write:

```
Task.WaitAll(blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image));
```

Comment: Just a question: Is there actually any difference if one calls `Task.WaitAll(blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream))` compared to synchronous call `blob.UploadFromStream(stream)`? I mean because we're waiting in current thread for the other one to complete... So current thread is not being released to thread pool as there's no async/await in this code... So basically as I see it both calls are identical.

Comment: On my machine(win8/net45/x64) this guy `blob.UploadFromStream(image);` runs in current thread, but this one `Task.WaitAll(blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(image));` runs operation in different thread and wait in the current for completion. 
So in both cases current thread is busy until operation completion, but in the second one additional thread is involved for actual operation.

Comment: From what you said, I can deduct that `UploadFromStream` is faster and uses less resources. In both cases, because it doesn't have to create a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

You're waiting for the task started with `Task.Run`. You want to wait for `UploadFromStreamAsync`. In fact I don't see why you need `Task.Run` here. It only makes things slower. You transfer work to the thread-pool, then wait for it to complete.

Just call the synchronous version of `UploadFromStreamAsync` if there is one. Or, call `Wait` on the task that `UploadFromStreamAsync` returns (less preferable).

You might want to revise your exception handling. You'll never find out about bugs in this method because all exceptions are thrown away.

Comment: The exception handling was only a temporary deal. I hadn't fully implemented the method yet. And just calling UploadFromStreamAsync didn't work either. But calling Task.WaitAll(UploadFromStreamAsync) ended up working.

Comment: You better just call the synchronous version directly. If that is not possible, call `Wait` on the task rather then `Task.WaitAll` which is needlessly complicated.